# Cancel an Observable from the producer side, not consumer side

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, observable

Cancelling from the consumer side, might be called using takeUntil, but that's not necessarily very dynamic. In this case, though, I am looking to cancel an Observable from the producer side of the equation, in the same way you might wish to cancel a Promise inside a promise chain (which is not very possible with the native utility).

Say I have this Observable being returned from a method. (This Queue library is a simple persistent queue that read/writes to a text file, we need to lock read/writes so nothing gets corrupted).

```
Queue.prototype.readUnique = function () {

    var ret = null;
    var lockAcquired = false;

    return this.obsEnqueue
        .flatMap(() => acquireLock(this))
        .flatMap(() => {
            lockAcquired = true;
            return removeOneLine(this)
        })
        .flatMap(val => {
            ret = val;   // this is not very good
            return releaseLock(this);
        })
        .map(() => {
            return JSON.parse(ret);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            if (lockAcquired) {
                return releaseLock(this);
            }
            else {
                return genericObservable();
            }
        });

};
```

I have 2 different questions -

1. If I cannot acquire the lock, how can I "cancel" the observable, to just send back an empty Observable with no result(s)? Would I really have to do if/else logic in each return call to decide whether the current chain is cancelled and if so, return an empty Observable? By empty, I mean an Observable that simple fires onNext/onComplete without any possibility for errors and without any values for onNext. Technically, I don't think that's an empty Observable, so I am looking for what that is really called, if it exists.
2. If you look at this particular sequence of code:

   ```
   .flatMap(() => acquireLock(this))
   .flatMap(() => {
       lockAcquired = true;
       return removeOneLine(this)
   })
   .flatMap(val => {
       ret = val;
       return releaseLock(this);
   })
   .map(() => {
       return JSON.parse(ret);
   })
   ```

what I am doing is storing a reference to ret at the top of the method and then referencing it again a step later. What I am looking for is a way to pass the value fired from removeOneLine() to JSON.parse(), without having to set some state outside the chain (which is simply inelegant).

Answer (score 3):

1) It depends on how your method `acquireLock` works - but I am assuming that it throws an error if it cannot acquire the lock, in that case you could *create* your stream with a `catch` and set the fallback stream to an empty one:

```
return Rx.Observable.catch(
        removeLine$,
        Rx.Observable.empty()
    );
```

2) To spare the stateful external variable you could simply chain a `mapTo`:

```
let removeLine$ = acquireLock(this)
    .flatMap(() => this.obsEnqueue
        .flatMap(() => removeOneLine(this))
        .flatMap(val => releaseLock(this).mapTo(val))
        .map(val => JSON.parse(val))
        .catch(() => releaseLock(this))
    );
```

Comment: thanks @olsn, I follow part 2, (although I don't know the difference between map and mapTo) but regarding part 1, I do not follow, do you mind explaining in other words?

Comment: part1 is basically the last 4 lines of the code-block (sorry, the answer might be a bit badly structued)
the difference between `map` and `mapTo` is just that `mapTo` takes directly an argument to _map to_, while `map` takes a function, so `.mapTo(val)` could be just as well be written as `.map(() => val)`

Comment: ok I will edit it as I understand it, please feel free to edit my edits :)

Comment: I am not sure I understand the Rx.Observable.catch construct yet, but I will look it up, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to your definition of cancel, it is to prevent an observable from sending a value downstream. To prevent an observable from pushing a value, you can use filter:

It can be as simple as:

```
observable.filter(_ => lockAcquired)
```

This will only send a notification downstream if `lockAcquired` is true.